# Is it possible to retrieve the row count impacted by Dapper query?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, dapper

I am trying to insert a record in SQL Server table using Dapper. I am able to insert records using `ExecuteScalarAsync` but it is not returning the impacted row count which is 1 in this case. I tried `Execute`, `ExecuteScalar` and query methods also.

`sqlCommand = @"Insert into PAYMENTS (TRANSACTION_NO, MEMBER_ID, PAID_AMOUNT, PAID_DATE) VALUES ( @TransactionNo, @MemberId,@PaidAmount,@PaidDate);`

```
var status = await con.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sqlCommand, details);
```

or

```
`var status = con.Execute<string>(sqlCommand, details);`
```

I just want to know if there is a way to retrieve this.

Comment: Have you tried ```int status = con.Execute(sqlCommand, details);``` ?

Comment: Hi fiji3300, yes I tried and no luck with that also.

Comment: Are you getting 0 as your return? Have you checked if the query does in fact change anything, then?

Comment: Yes. It is returning 0. when I check `con.ExecuteScalar(sqlCommand, details)` return value, it is returning null. The insert command is successful and hence should return 1.

Comment: could you maybe post the sqlCommand?

Comment: I am using Dapper library. Is it because of that?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is looking for this, I could get the count of rows impacted with `ExecuteAsync`